# Org-mode: Entering time with academic quarter as 2ct

Tags: org-mode

One can enter the time `14:00` by typing `2pm`.  One should also be
able to enter `14:15` by typing `2ct`.  ('cum tempore' indicating an
academic quarter.)  Is it possible to get this behaviour?

(Or 14ct.  Ideally, one would have a function to determine whether an academic hour is likely to be am or pm.)

Comment: When adding an option for `2ct` (cum tempore) it might be a good idea to add an option for `2st` (sine tempore), too.

Comment: @zngguvnf, it wouldn't save you any keystroke, being equivalent to `2pm`; would you want it just for symmetry?

Comment: @Thoothrot: Year just for symmetry. And because I think the default option (ct vs. st) often depends on the people around you. When implementing `2ct` and `2st` you could `setq` your default option.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get this behaviour but it needs updates to org mode core rexexps for matching time strings and corresponding replacement codes. All these can be updated. Start with constants `org-plain-time-of-day-regexp` and `org-plain-time-extension-regexp` and function `org-read-date-analyze`.

Your best bet is to do a feature request to org mode or even better, submit a patch. See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html